# Need to return the first instance found, instead of all

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I have had make do over the last few years which heavily leans on the users entering in data in a somewhat correct order (i know, first mistake).

The idea is that the users enter a item with the category of CRT in the first 7 lines...and only one.  Some times there may be others with this category, but i only want the first one.  Now, users sometimes enter the item in after the first 7 rows...leading to another problem.  Here is my original query:

```
Select distinct
        d.Job_Number as Rig,
    case d.Customer_Name
        when 'case' then 'diff case'
        else '******'
    end as Parent_Customer,
        d.Customer_Name,
    case d.Reference_Location2
        when 'case' then 'diff case'
        else '******'
    end as Size,
    case d.Office_code
        when 'case' then 'diff case'
        else '****'
    end as Office,
        d.Rental_Ticket,
    case d.job_type
        when 'case' then 'diff case'
        else '0'
    end as Billable,
    d.Reference_Location5 as TT

from HP_View_DEL_Ticket_Header_Master as d
left join CSView_INVC_Header_Master as i --left join to report jobs that have not been invoiced
on d.Rental_Ticket = i.Rental_Ticket_or_Tag_Number
join CSView_DEL_Ticket_Lines_Master as l
on d.Rental_Ticket = l.Rental_Ticket
where (d.Ticket_Month between 7 and 7 and d.Ticket_Year = 2017)-- or (d.Ticket_Month between 12 and 12 and d.Ticket_Year = 2016))

and d.Rental_Ticket not in (select dticket from deltick_void)
and d.Ticket_Type = 'D'
and d.Posted_Flag = -1
and l.Row_Counter between 1 and 7 --Currently how I get the correct record, problem is its sometimes not entered in the first 7 rows.
and l.Category_Code = 'CRT'
order by Parent_Customer
```

I am needing one Ticket number, to one CRT item (the CRT first item).  I've tried doing something in the where clause to find the top CRT items but didn't work the way i figured it would.

Any help would be great.

Thanks
BD

EDIT:
Expected OUTPUT

```
Rig Parent_Customer Customer_Name   Size    Office  Rental_Ticket   Billable    TT
RIG 642 A   A   5 to 5.5    City    12627   0   YES
RIG 525 B   B   5 1/2   City 2  12628   0   YES
RIG 603 C   C   9 5/8   City 3  12634   0   NO
```

Incorrect OUTPUT:

```
Rig Parent_Customer Customer_Name   Size    Office  Rental_Ticket   Billable    TT
RIG 642 A   A   5 to 5.5    City    12627   0   YES
RIG 642 A   A   5 to 5.5    City    12627   0   YES
```

Because the query finds more than one 'CRT' on the Rental Ticket, it returns two records that are the same for the columns I have selected.  I am wanting to use ONLY the first one it finds.

Comment: Can you show what you'd expect the output to look like? FWIW, the answer is probably going to involve the `row_number` function.

Comment: Edited with expected and incorrect output